# I am having problems with booleans staying as I define them

Tags: python, boolean

```
B=False

def func1():
    def func2():
        global B
        if B == True:
            print("True")
            B=False
        else:
            print("False")

    B=True
    func2()
func1()
```

This is an example of the problem I am having, when I set a variable as a Boolean within a function, the Boolean seems to change when brought to another function, e.g. here the Boolean B is set to True in func1() but in func2(), where B should still be True, the output of the code is False, signifying the Boolean has become False.

Comment: You're declaring B as global inside func2, but not in func1.

Comment: You might want to take a look at *nonlocal*

Comment: Don't ever write `if B == True:`.  Just do `if B:`, and `if not B:` in place of `if B == False:`.  One of the beauties of Python is the concept of "truthy" objects, and this gives you more flexibility.